# Proving Kolmogorov's continuity condition holds for Brownian motion?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Let $B(t)$ be $n$-dimensional Brownian motion.

I want to show that $E|B(t)-B(s)|^4 = n(n+2)|t-s|^2$ so that Kolmogorov's continuity theorem can be used to show that Brownian motion has a continuous version.

I tried the following:

$$E|B(t)-B(s)|^4 = E\left[ \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (B_i(t)-B_i(s))^2}^4 \right]=E\left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (B_i(t)-B_i(s))^2\right)^2 \right]$$

$$= \sum_{i,j=1}^n E\left[(B_i(t)-B_i(s))^2(B_j(t)-B_j(s))^2\right]$$

Since the individual components of Brownian motion are independent, if $i \neq j$ we get

$$E[(B_i(t)-B_i(s))^2(B_j(t)-B_j(s))^2] = (t-s)^2$$

while if $i=j$ we get

$$E[(B_i(t)-B_i(s))^4]= 3(t-s)^2$$

Adding together we see the RHS is then equal to

$$3n (t-s)^2 + (n^2-n)(t-s)^2$$

and, since $3n + n^2 - n = n(n+2)$, the result follows by Kolmogorov's Continuity Theorem that a continuous version of Brownian motion exists.

Is this correct?

Comment: To show that a continuous version of n-dimensional BM exists you just prove this for $n=1$ and then take $n$ independent copies (by going to to a product space).

Comment: Your calculation seems to be fine.Altermatively you could use the scaling property, i.e. the fact that $B_t-B_s$ equals in distriution $\sqrt{t-s} B_1$ which yields immediately that $$\mathbb{E}(|B_t-B_s|^4) = |t-s|^2 \mathbb{E}(|B_1|^4).$$